# How to hide VNC notification?

Tags: vnc, windows-xp

When ever I access a windows machine through VNC from ubuntu the icon changes and notifies the user that someone is logged into the system. Is it possible to hide that notification?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with Ubuntu, I'm afraid. This is something that the VNC server software is responsible for. The way of setting it also varies from server to server.

Here's [an example of how you might do it with RealVNC](http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/69/How+can+I+disable+the+Connection+Notification+pop-up,+that+appears+when+a+new+user+connects+to+VNC+Server%3F):

> To disable the Connection Alert feature, set the "ConnNotifyTimeout" setting in the VNC Server "Expert" settings tab to "0".